# Why can you assign nullptr to std::string?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, stdstring, null-pointer

So today I wrote a fairly hard to find bug where I initialized a std::string to nullptr (not a pointer to std::string, but the value itself). I've found apparently it's only possible to do in C++11 or later with clang.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class Meh{
    int x;
};
class Foo
{
private:
  std::string x=nullptr;
  Meh y=nullptr; //remove this line and it compiles
public:
  std::string z=nullptr;
};

int main(void)
{
    Foo f;
    cout << f.z;
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I tried assigning nullptr to just a random instance of a class and it didn't work. What magic is in string that allows this to work, and in what way is this even valid syntax? I assumed I would be met with a type casting error in this case.

For reference I compiled with this:

```
clang++ test.cpp -O3 -g -fno-inline -std=c++11 -Wall
```

It gave no form of warnings, though it would error out if not using C++11

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's simply because there are [constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) (number (5) in the link) and [assignment operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) (number (3) in the link) for [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) that accept a `const char*`, and hence the `nullptr` matches.

Before C++11 (and therefore before `nullptr`), the same problem occurred when you tried to construct from `0` or `NULL`. All those cases were illegal and result in undefined behaviour, although at least one STL (RogueWave?) accepted it in the past and generated an empty string.

Comment: Worth noting that this is Undefined Behaviour™

Comment: @Earlz `nullptr` didn't exist before C++11.

Comment: @Earlz Because C++98/C++03 does not have `nullptr`.

Comment: @DanielFrey ah, I guess it's standard libraries that provide nullptr emulation by some nullptr_t type that I assume is just a void*

Comment: @Earlz Probably not `void*` but a macro which is a literal `0`. A literal `0` is not just an integer, but also a valid pointer - there are special rules in the standard for that.

Comment: @Earlz My old MSVC2008 accept `std::string x = NULL;` at compile time, but throws fatal error at runtime.

Comment: @Deduplicator Sounds like a good idea, but it won't prevent `0` or `NULL` to trigger the bug again. And checking the pointer against `0` to throw an exception was rejected about 15 years ago when I suggested it (and I probably wasn't the only one). Maybe STLs could do it, at least in debug mode. Also... damn... I'm old :(

Comment: Assigning from `0` is "fine" (as in, won't compile). That one is ambiguous with the assignment operator taking a `charT`. :/

Comment: @Deduplicator Perhaps a core language tweak that makes integer null pointer constants convert better to `nullptr_t` than to other pointer types will do the trick (along with a deleted overload for `nullptr_t`)?

Comment: @T.C. That would break existing code. I even have a usecase for that where I accept a literal zero *only*. No other integer, no `nullptr`.

Comment: @DanielFrey Got an example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77934/discussion-between-daniel-frey-and-t-c).

Comment: I don't think this answers the question of *why*, only the different and not asked question of *how*. The *why* is that there's no good reason for it, that it is a design error / oversight. `std::basic_string` is a very complex beast, but most all of the complexity is concerned with more or less useless stuff; a little added safety would IMHO have been well worth the marginal increase in complexity.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can you assign `nullptr` to `std::string`?

You no longer can, and it only used to be possible because of a historical design flaw.

As of C++23, `std::string x = nullptr;` is ill-formed. The reason why it worked originally is because of a [constructor which accepts `const CharT*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), which could also be a `nullptr`:

```cpp
basic_string( const CharT* s, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

However, this constructor loses in overload resolution against the new constructor:

```cpp
basic_string( std::nullptr_t ) = delete;
```

If you tried to compile your code in C++23, [you would get a compiler error](https://godbolt.org/z/v3xa3vfKd). In C++11, it would be undefined behavior to run your code.
Since it's pointless to allow `= nullptr` as it's always a bug, [P2166: A Proposal to Prohibit std::basic_string and std::basic_string_view construction from nullptr](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2166r1.html) proposed to disallow it.