# Could std::string::c_str() ever return nullptr?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, nullptr

I have read several topics here and on other resources and did not found exact answer. The answer seems to be **never**. Please confirm.

---

Stop. Not never. As noted in [Why can you assign nullptr to std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30268904/why-can-you-assign-nullptr-to-stdstring):

```
std::string str {nullptr};  // Undefined behavior
```

So if this will not throw (depends on implementation), `c_str()` could return `(char_t*)nullptr`.

I believe there are no other ways to get `nullptr` from `c_str()`. But must ask StackOverflow community to be sure. Thanks for attention.

Comment: No, c_str()  will always return a null-terminated C-style string, assuming no prior undefined behaviour.

Comment: Passing `nullptr` to `string::string` will just make the string try to interpret `(char*)nullptr` as a pointer to a c-string. It will still copy the mis-pointed c-string to its managed storage

Comment: @NeilButterworth: "null-terminated C-style string" is a bit redundant, since a C-style string is by definition a null-terminated array of characters. You cannot have a "non-null-terminated C-style string", if you will. That wouldn't be a C-style string.

Comment: @Kerrek In my experience a little redundancy is never a bad thing when it comes to explanations.

Comment: `std::string str {nullptr};  // Undefined behavior` as you note, this is undefined behavior, so all bets are off. You can't use something that happens after you invoke undefined behavior as a counter-example.

Comment: @kyb: You're asking about what happens after undefined behavior. Well, once you have undefined behavior, the behavior of your program has become *undefined*. What `.c_str` does is whatever it does, and it can in no way be relied upon.

Comment: @NicolBolas. No please reread question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Since `c_str` returns a pointer `p` to a null-terminated array of characters, there must be some value `i >= 0` such that `p[i] == '\0'`, and thus `p` cannot be null.

Comment: What if nullptr can be dereferenced on your platform and returns 0?

Comment: @Yakk: Every `p[k]` must point to an object for `0 <= k <= i`, and the address of an object is never a null pointer.